# Regex to match at least one of three sub-patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an identifier that is made of at least one of three parts of various lengths. The first part are capital letters, which can be matched by `[A-Z]+`. The second part are small letters which can be matched by `[a-z]+`. The third part are digits which can be matched by `[0-9]+`. They must occur in this specific order. So all the following are correct identifiers: `A`, `h`, `3`, `Ab`, `AA9`, `abc23`, `Hyy2346`. They should be matched by the pattern. Examples of incorrect identifiers include: `wD`, `99A`, `6a5`, etc. or anything that contains non-alphanumerical characters.

The problem is that if I do for example `[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*` such pattern also matches an empty string which is not a correct identifier. How to make a pattern so that the length of the matched string is at least 1?

This is a simplified version of the more complicated problem I am facing in which I have to match entries in certain ancient scripts. I used `[A-Z]+` etc. above as examples to illustrate my sub-patterns, but the actual sub-patterns I have are much more complicated. Nevertheless they are all of the form `(a class of characters and words)+`. Also: I am doing this in JavaScript. Also: I need to do this in a single regex.

I could try something like `([A-Z]+[a-z]*[0-9]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]+)` but because my actual sub-patterns are much longer than those `[A-Z]+` etc., the result is very long and I am wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient.

Comment: "I have to match entries in certain ancient scripts." Does that mean that you can have multiple matches?

Comment: Yes, the texts I work with contain many of them, and I have to write a regex to find them. For that reason, none of the solutions using ^ and $ work.

Comment: Note that `[A-Z]+[a-z]*[0-9]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]+` can be shortened to `[A-Z]+[a-z]*[0-9]*|[a-z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+`

Comment: Also you can eventually write that: `(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*`

Comment: If you can have multiple matches in one string then `9aA` should be 3 different matches, right? `wD` that you say is invalid would be 2 matches.

Comment: ... and if not, what are the delimiters? You haven't shown us an example of your input data and described what delimiters there are between the multiple matches.

Comment: You could add a word boundary: [`^\b[A-Z]*[a-z]*\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/moA3YV/1)

Comment: 9aA is an incorrect identifier so it should not match, but 9, a, and A are correct identifiers so there should be 3 separate matches for them. That's correct. I cannot use word boundaries.

Comment: @Amadeus I think you need to clarify this where you now say _"Examples of incorrect identifiers"_.  `wD`, `99A` and `6a5` would all be two identifiers each. Anyway, I've updated the answer to match the information you've given in comments.

Comment: @Amadeus Have you had any chance to try it out? If you have any issues, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Add a positive lookahead that matches one character at the beginning.

```
^(?=.)[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*$
```

Or just check that the string isn't empty before testing it with the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to make a positive lookahead to check that the identifier contains at least one character in the group `[A-Za-z0-9]`:

```
((?=[A-Za-z\d])[A-Z]*[a-z]*\d*)
```

- `(` - start of capture group

  - `(?=[A-Za-z\d])` - positive lookahead for any of `[A-Za-z\d]`
  - `[A-Z]*` - zero or more `[A-Z]`
  - `[a-z]*` - zero or more `[a-z]`
  - `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `)` - end of capture group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A76cn1/1)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `/^[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*$/` pattern in combination with a length-check of the matched result will do the trick:

```js
"0,A,h,3,Ab,AA9,abc23,Hyy2346,wD,99A,6a5,#123,#,   ,".split(",").forEach(v=>
  console.log(v,!!v.match(/^[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*$/)?.[0]?.length)
);
```

The pattern will return `null` if the regexp was not matched. The double negation (`!!`) of the matching string (`v.match(...)?.[0]?.length`) will exclude the empty string as a possible result. The "optional chaining operator" `?.[0]` will get the first array element if it exists, otherwise `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```